# AsyncFileUpload SerializationException

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using the AsyncFileUpload control to upload images.
It works fine from localhost, but when I uploaded it on server I get the following error.

I can't even understand the reason of this error. I'll appreciate any answer.

**This is the Method that I'm using**

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e) 
{
    string email = WriteYourEmailTXT.Text;
    var dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).ToString("ddMMyyyy");
    string parentFolder = Server.MapPath("uploads");
    string childFolder = parentFolder + "\\" + email + "\\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(childFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(childFolder);

    string counter = getCount();
    if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile) {
        string ext = getExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
        string finalName = dt + "_" + counter + ext;
        string finalPath = childFolder + finalName;
        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(finalPath);
        SetCount();
        SetFileName(finalName);
    }
}

protected void SetCount() 
{
    HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["CountPhoto"];
    int cookieNum = 0;
    if (aCookie != null)
        if (aCookie.Value != "")
            cookieNum = int.Parse(aCookie.Value.ToString());

    string newvalue = (cookieNum + 1).ToString();
    Response.Cookies["CountPhoto"].Value = newvalue;
}

protected void SetFileName(string fileName) 
{
    HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["FileName"];
    var filename = "";
    if (aCookie != null)
        if (aCookie.Value != "") {
            filename = aCookie.Value;
        }
    string newFileName = filename + "," + fileName;
    Response.Cookies["FileName"].Value = newFileName;
}
```

**Error**

> Unable to serialize the session state.
>   In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode,
>   ASP.NET will serialize the session
>   state objects, and as a result
>   non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not
>   permitted. The same restriction
>   applies if similar serialization is
>   done by the custom session state store
>   in 'Custom' mode.
>
> **Stack Trace:** [SerializationException: Type
>   'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' in
>   Assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.]
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type) +7733643
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context) +258
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   +111    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector
>   surrogateSelector, StreamingContext
>   context, SerObjectInfoInit
>   serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter
>   converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
>   +161    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector
>   surrogateSelector, StreamingContext
>   context, SerObjectInfoInit
>   serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter
>   converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
>   +51    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders,
>   __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +410
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph,
>   Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +134
>   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object
>   value, BinaryWriter writer) +1577
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to
>   serialize the session state. In
>   'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode,
>   ASP.NET will serialize the session
>   state objects, and as a result
>   non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not
>   permitted. The same restriction
>   applies if similar serialization is
>   done by the custom session state store
>   in 'Custom' mode.]
>   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object
>   value, BinaryWriter writer) +1662
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object
>   value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter
>   writer) +606
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Stream stream) +239
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]&
>   buf, Int32& length) +72
>   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id,
>   SessionStateStoreData item, Object
>   lockId, Boolean newItem) +87
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs) +560
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with a configuration difference in IIS between your local machine and that of your web server.

Your server seems to be setup to handle the session by using a StateServer (another PC to handle a lot of the user data in memory) or by using your SQL Server (your database stores the user objects in special table).  In order to transfer the data to the State Server or your Database server IIS will serialize your session information to transport it to the other server.  Basically, this takes all the details for a given object and converts them to XML so that the object can be "saved" and "loaded" to/from memory as needed.

The specific problem in this case is that the 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' class does not support serialization.  Usually this problem occurs with classes written by our own developers and we can just add a  attribute to the class but it appears here that the problem exists in a class provided by the .NET framework.  I'm afraid you will need to find a way to work around the issue such as writing your own class or not making use of this one.

Comment: Also, you can try switching how the sessions are handled on your web server through IIS configuration, but I'm going to guess that's out of your control.